# Ignore spaces and break words by wrapping anywhere inside a text-area

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have a text-area wrap at any point and ignore spaces?

This is the behavior I have now:

```
| I want it to    |
| wrap anywhere   |
```

And this is what I'd like:

```
| I want it to wr |
| ap anywhere     |
```

Comment: Your example of what you want does *not* have spaces ignored; it has “I want it”, not “Iwantit”. And it seems rather pointless to want to *break w ords* within an element that is intended for user input.

Comment: Answered quickly as I found the answer while I was submitting it here. Thought someone else might find it useful. I'm not up on the etiquette of posting, just trying to help others who come along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution by using the css3 "word-break: break-all" property.

```
textarea {
    border-width:1px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

See [CSS3 word-break Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) for more info.

Comment: [Please don't use w3schools as a resource](http://w3fools.com). Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) instead.

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks for sharing. I thought W3schools was affiliated with W3C. I just like the way their pages are layed out a lot more that mdn, and from when I've used them many times in the past they seem to be fine. And its hard not to click on them when they're always the first Google result. But I'll keep that in mind. @JosephSilber

Comment: @eshellborn - [They are notorious for search ranking manipulation](http://www.impressivewebs.com/web-development-search-results-manipulated/). I actively work to never click on any of their links.

Comment: Changed link as suggested by @JosephSilber

Comment: I understand they may not always be reliable, but I am grateful for their existence, they have come to my aid many times. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120621/w3fools-alternatives